# Some sites won't load iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to insert the following iframe into twitch.tv:

```
<iframe name="cleverbot" width="540" height="340" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" src="http://www.cleverbot.com/cleverbotif"></iframe>
```

I am doing this by simply right clicking any random element, inspecting, and editing html, where I just copy and paste the iframe element after the selected one. I have tried inserting the iframe after many different elements, but nothing ever appears. It appears that an iframe window exists, as it does move other elements around it, but it is completely blank. This same thing happens with google.com. I can insert this iframe into other sites, like this one, and it works fine.

I have tried googling this issue, but I all see are question related to sites not allowing themselves to be iframed, instead of sites not allowing iframes.

Basically, my question is, do some sites just not allow iframes to be loaded into them?

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: so your iframe element does not get created or it gets created but does not load content?

Comment: I think it's the latter, the content doesn't load, since there is a blank rectangle with the same size specifications specified in the iframe element.

Comment: then is probably a cross origin issue.

Comment: The link you posted does state that a website can prevent loading of iframes from a different origin if it uses uses certain X-Frame-Options, so maybe that's the cause.

Comment: Also, twitch is using HTTPS, and your cleverbot dont

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this from console - 
creating new node with your iframe and then appending it to page's body.

`var node = document.createElement('div');
 node.innerHTML = '<iframe name="cleverbot" width="540" height="340" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" src="http://www.cleverbot.com/cleverbotif"></iframe>'
 document.body.appendChild(node);`